# why zuul gateway application took so long to shut down in a graceful way

Tags: java, spring-boot, shell, centos, netflix-zuul

I have a situation while updating and restarting applications by my self developed CICD module.

I have Eureka as registry center,and zuul as gateway.

By running shell script using kill -15 command, I want to shutdown my applications in a graceful way. And that shell script runs correctly.

But so far during my testing and observing this CICD module, I found that restarting zuul gateway application will take a huge long time to shutdown (about 5 minutes waiting, the other applications will take only less than 5 seconds).

As far as I know, springboot will shut down the threadpools at first to reject resolving new request, then let the remaining threads to be done, and then shut down the application context after that.

When restarting my gateway application , I have done these steps:

1. pull down this gateway service from nginx upstream;
2. pull down this gateway service from eureka server, but not shutting down;
3. wait for 90 seconds

```
30 (eureka server refresh to readable server list cache default 30s )
+ 30 (eureka client fetching interval default 30s)
+ 30 (ribbon refreshing after eureka client fething server list cache default 30s)
```

4. use `kill -15 applicationPid` to shutdown the application
5. do a loop to see if this pid was shut down.
6. restart the new application
7. wait for 60 seconds if application is reachable from eureka server's api

```
30 (eureka client fetching interval default 30s)
+ 30 (ribbon refreshing after eureka client fething server list cache default 30s)
```

8. pull up this gateway service from nginx

Testing plan is shown below:

1. By sending request from 20 threads, each of the thread will send 3 request per second.
2. 2 Linux servers A and B, each of them has a gateway service on it.
3. when shuting down A's gateway, nginx will point to B and let B bear the job, and the same options when B's gateway is shuting down.

As I observed, all requests will correctly resolved and no errors turned out during restarting the gateway applications.

But I don't know why that shutting down gateway application will take so much time. there are totally no request comming in after nginx was pull down, and the application will still remain stucking there and seems there are no useful logs to show what's going on.

After several minutes the application will then finally shut down.

If I send no requests, the gateway application will shut down immediately and gracefully.

when it's stuck, the console log is shown below:

```
....normal log....
2021-07-19 14:42:08.195 [app:web-gateway,traceId:,spanId:,parentId:] [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  | EurekaServiceRegistry.java:65 | o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry | Unregistering application WEB-GATEWAY with eureka with status DOWN
2021-07-19 14:42:08.195 [app:web-gateway,traceId:,spanId:,parentId:] [SpringContextShutdownHook] WARN  | DiscoveryClient.java:1351 | c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient | Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1626676928195, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
2021-07-19 14:42:08.195 [app:web-gateway,traceId:,spanId:,parentId:] [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] INFO  | DiscoveryClient.java:870 | c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient | DiscoveryClient_WEB-GATEWAY/192.168.24.200:web-gateway:8005:NEW_GATEWAY_DEFAULT_GROUP: registering service...
2021-07-19 14:42:08.199 [app:web-gateway,traceId:,spanId:,parentId:] [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] INFO  | DiscoveryClient.java:879 | c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient | DiscoveryClient_WEB-GATEWAY/192.168.24.200:web-gateway:8005:NEW_GATEWAY_DEFAULT_GROUP - registration status: 204
2021-07-19 14:42:08.252 [app:web-gateway,traceId:,spanId:,parentId:] [Thread-17] INFO  | EurekaNotificationServerListUpdater.java:71 | c.n.n.l.EurekaNotificationServerListUpdater | Shutting down the Executor for EurekaNotificationServerListUpdater
2021-07-19 14:42:08.745 [app:web-gateway,traceId:,spanId:,parentId:] [SpringContextShutdownHook] INFO  | DirectJDKLog.java:173 | o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol | Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8005"]
2021-07-19 14:43:18.087 [app:web-gateway,traceId:,spanId:,parentId:] [AsyncResolver-bootstrap-executor-0] INFO  | ConfigClusterResolver.java:43 | c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver | Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
.....stuck here.....
```

Because I have manually pull down gateway application from eureka, so here application log shows code 204 is acceptable.

I have once guess that if it is the code 204 error to stuck application to shut down. But other applications which also bear the requests will shut down immediately and gracefully after the kill -15 command is called.Only gateway application will stuck.

Could any one tell me how to checkout from the stuck application to see what's going on when the kill -15 command was done?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved.

Never questioning a stable structure....

I have got something wrong to the threadpool so while killing with `kill -15`,my customized thread pool have so many tasks that was not ended.

by checking stack of JVM I've found that problem. by correcting the code,the problem solved.